# Theorems for convergence for alternating sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

I was just wondering whether there are any theorems that relates to convergence of an alternating *sequence*. For example, $(a_n) = (1, -1/2, 1/3, -1/4, 1/5, -1/6, \ldots)$. Are there any theorems I can use to show convergence/divergence when terms of a sequence changes sign? I know that $(a_n) \rightarrow a \implies (|a_n|) \rightarrow |a|$ but the converse is not true.

Comment: If an alternating _sequence_ converges, then, necessarily, the limit is $=0$.

Comment: Cool, are there any sufficient conditions for convergence of an alternating sequence?

Comment: Drop the minus signs, and ask if that positive series converges to zero.

Comment: @user40333  is it possible you're asking if the *sum* of this sequence converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarise what was mentioned in the comments.

If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a convergent alternating sequence, then it must converge to $0$. Now note that if $a_1 > 0$, then $a_n = (-1)^{n+1}b_n$ where $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a strictly positive sequence and $a_n \to 0$ if and only if $b_n \to 0$.

*Note:* in your post you say $a_n \to a \Rightarrow |a_n| \to |a|$, but the converse is not true. That is correct, however, if $a = 0$, the converse is true (it is the only case where the converse is true).

So, if you're trying to determine whether a sequence converges, and you know it is alternating, then you know what it must converge to, and once you know that, you can just work with the corresponding positive sequence.